# What does "LL" mean on BB spindle?

Tags: shimano

What does that "LL" mean, stamped (along with the length) on my Mountain Bike's  Shimano BB spindle?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me. Any chance you can post a photo?

Comment: [Sheldon Brown](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html) has a very comprehensive page on bottom brackets but no explanation as to what the LL refers to and given its context it does not seem that obvious either.  I am guessing here but it maybe a contraction for overall length given its usage.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know anything about bottom brackets, but I found [this document](https://www.bbinstitute.com/dl/dx_demo_chapter_10.pdf) which says (on page 16):

> Shimano cartidge-bearing bottom-bracket spindles are marked with letter codes that correspond to different length spindles. These codes and the corresponding spindle lengths are:
>
> **Code Length**
>
> MM 107mm and 110.5mm
>
> LL 113mm
>
> D-H 115mm
>
> YL 116mm
>
> XL 118mm
>
> ZL 121mm
>
> NL 122.5mm
>
> EL 127.5mm

Answer (score 2):

This document appears to conflict with a previous answer. Check out spindle length in the following:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for bringing this up. I know you can't put pictures in a comment but you have posted this as an answer and this actually raises more questions than it answers in current form. Can you edit/reword this into an actual answer that correct's Luke's statement? Even if it is 9 years old, this is a knowledge base and correct information is always of value. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the third entry in the BB chart says *LL113 (E)* under the row for spindle length. This seems to confirm the other answer, not disprove it.